# How do I add php limit and order to the returning children?

Tags: php, arrays, limit

Two things really.

1. I'm trying to limit the returned children, as an example 8 articles. I've tried array_slice and other techniques though just can't get anything to work.
2. I'd also like to return these children in ascending order based on my 'modified_date' column in my database.

Really appreciate any guidance on this, been working hard for nights, can't get anything to work :(

```
<?php
    // get all pages
    $pages = new TFW_Navigation($pageNav);
    $pages = $pages->getNavigation();
      foreach ($pages as $index => $topPage)
    {
    $children = $topPage->getChildren(null,true);
    if (!empty($children)) {
    foreach($children as $child) {
  ?>

  <article class="<?=$child->ext_column_1 ?>">
     <a href="<?= $child->url ?>" class='article-border'>
        <img src="<?=$child->ext_column_2 ?>" alt="">
          <header>
              <h3>
                  <?= $child->ext_column_3 ?>
              </h3>
          </header>
          <footer>
              <p>
                <?php echo date("d F Y", strtotime($child->last_modified))."<span class='sprite article-link'></span>" ?>
              </p>
          </footer>
      </a>
  </article>

  <?php
        }
      }
    }
  ?>
```

If more information is needed, please let me know.

Thanks, Barry

Comment: what is the type of returned value of `$topPage->getChildren(null,true);`? why can't use array_slice?

Comment: `$children = array_slice($topPage->getChildren(null,true),2);` Nothing is showing?

Comment: check the actual class/type of returned value and if it's actually an array - check type of indexes (whether it is associative array or not). If nothing helps - just add variable $i, increase it manually each time and `break` when reaching 8

Answer (score 0):

Add a `break` statement.

```
foreach($children as $childIndex => $child) {
    if ($childIndex > 8) {
        break;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alien, nothing changes, still showing the full 40+. And If i remove the } down after the break, nothing shows.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($childIndex)` and see what you get

Comment: 13 December 2014
int(6)
Ne plus rester en pyjama(example) `int(0)
int(1)
int(2)
int(3)
int(4)
int(5)
int(6)
int(7)
int(8)
int(0)
int(1)
int(2)
int(3)
int(0)
int(1)
int(2)
int(3)
int(4)
int(5)
int(0)
int(1)...` It seems to be spitting out the amount of children per parent.

Comment: It's stopping at 8 then moving on to the next page. This is doing exactly what you asked for.

Comment: I see, but what I need is to return only 8, not matter how many pages, this is the problem, how to stop it moving to the next page if we have already shown 8?

Answer (score 0):

1. To limit your array , using array_slice is a good solution

> ```
> $firstEight =  array_slice($children, 0, 8); // First 8 items
> ```

2. To return array in ascending order based on your modified_date column, you have to do that from sql query.

> ```
> $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE x = y ORDER BY last_modified ASC";
> ```

and also you can limit the results from sql .

> ```
> $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE x = y ORDER BY last_modified ASC LIMIT 0,8";
> ```

// Using

```
<?php
    // get all pages
    $pages = new TFW_Navigation($pageNav);
    $pages = $pages->getNavigation();
      foreach ($pages as $index => $topPage)
    {
    $children = $topPage->getChildren(null,true);
    $firstEight = array_slice($children, 0, 8);
    if (!empty($firstEight)) {
    foreach($firstEight as $child) {
  ?>

  <article class="<?=$child->ext_column_1 ?>">
     <a href="<?= $child->url ?>" class='article-border'>
        <img src="<?=$child->ext_column_2 ?>" alt="">
          <header>
              <h3>
                  <?= $child->ext_column_3 ?>
              </h3>
          </header>
          <footer>
              <p>
                <?php echo date("d F Y", strtotime($child->last_modified))."<span class='sprite article-link'></span>" ?>
              </p>
          </footer>
      </a>
  </article>

  <?php
        }
      }
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the sql as everything is all configured in the CMS. Just wondering how I would add `$firstEight =  array_slice($children, 0, 8);` to my existing code?

Comment: I've edited my post, copy the entire code and replace with yours, let me know if worked or not.

Comment: No errors, but again, still showing all the articles? Just don't understand what's wrong. I also var_dump($children); everything is returned. Maybe we need to go up one level, $pages?

Comment: Can you do a var_dump to $children ? var_dump($children); , post here first 2 elements

Comment: Sorry about the mess, also had to chop lots of limited char... `array(9) { [0]=> object(Navigation_PageItem)#32 (33) { ["page_id"]=> string(2) "28" ["location_type"]=> string(8) "WORKAREA" ["location_name"]=> string(6) "htdocs" ["output"]=> string(3) "web" ["parent_page_id"]=> string(2) "20" ["language"]=> string(2) "fr" ["precedence"]=> string(1) "1" ["file_name"]=>  ["last_modified"]=> string(19) "2014-12-10 16:50:26" ["url"]=> string(49) "/fr/health/easy-ways-to-eat-healthily.php"  ["childs"]=> array(0) { } } [1]=> object(Navigation_PageItem)#35 (33) { ["page_id"]=> string(2)`

Comment: Each page/object is a record in the database I think, and the children are the sub pages to some of the main pages. If that makes sense, in their own directory.

Comment: As you can see the start is array(9) which means that are just 9 arrays there, no 40+ , So the code work correct.

Comment: Yes I realised that, though still see 40+ articles and about 2000+ lines of xml via the dump(). What do you think?

Comment: well, I don't know what you have there, run echo json_encode($children);  instead of var_dump  and the entire result put in on http://pastebin.com/ and give me the link to check it .

Comment: Again, had to limit the amount, just to much data, thanks in advance CarcaBot http://pastebin.com/9jwRzhme

Comment: I think this is a little better clearer styling http://pastebin.com/u9KbqZM6. Again, any help with this much appreciated, Barry